Reset IAM rights on Azure storage account/container
We are moving from on-premise share to the Azure storage account. We will be using blob storage.  Currently, there is some on-premise folder structure that needs to be mirrored in the cloud and there are access permissions set up on each folder. Each time new folder is added, automatic script deletes all permissions from folders (in case someone added some folder permissions without our knowledge) and deleted permissions are being recreated again after new folder is added. So basically access permissions reset is being done.
My question is, does permission reset like mentioned above makes sense to do within Azure? Or is there a better way? I will be creating storage account/container and assigning rights using terraform. I know that there are rights inherited from resource group/subscription etc. so we want to only focus on storage account/container. Currently, we are not the only ones able to assign rights to storage accounts in our subscription so we want to be sure, that each time we run new folder creation, assigned rights are according to our best practices.
Thank you.

In Azure, instead of resetting permissions regularly, it's best to use Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) to manage access rights systematically and leverage Azure Policies to enforce security standards. Automating this with Terraform ensures consistency and alignment with best practices, eliminating the need for manual permission resets. @nmNtFnd

The problem is, when there is someone with enough permissions and does not know about our terraform infrastructure. Instead, sees azure resources and adjusts them according to some ticket received from ITSM tool.

To reduce the risk of unauthorized alterations by well-meaning insiders, it's advisable to implement Azure Policy. This tool audits and automatically reverts unapproved resource configurations, thus ensuring adherence to your organization's standards, even when direct changes occur outside of Terraform workflows. @nmNtFnd

@nmNtFnd can you please confirm if you will be using Azure Blob Storage or a File share? If you are using blob storage the approach should be to make Terraform the only way to implement changes to RBAC, so accounts of whoever works tickets don't have access to make changes, only the identity that runs Terraform deployments has relevant access. I do not agree with mixing Terraform and Azure Policy as you can get into cases where Azure Policy makes a change that Terraform then tries to undo. In such an environment Azure Policy should be audit-only.

Currently, it is planned that blob storage will be used.
